# Save IAuthSession inside AuthProvider.IsAuthorized()

Tags: servicestack

I created my custom `AuthUserSession` and my custom `AuthProvider` and I registered the `AuthFeature` inside the `AppHostBase`.

The authentication process is managed by the underlying ASP.NET application which puts in session (ASP.NET session) the informations I need.

Inside `AuthProvider.IsAuthorized()` I check the informations from the ASP.NET session and return true or false if the user is logged or not.

Now I would like to use my custom `AuthUserSession` inside my services.

I set the `AuthUserSession`'s properties inside `AuthProvider.IsAuthorized()` but I get empty properties when I try to access them inside my services using `SessionAs<MyCustomUserSession>()` (even during the same request) because I don't save the `AuthUserSession`, I think.

I can't figure out how to save the `AuthUserSession` from `AuthProvider.IsAuthorized()`.
I tried to make my custom `AuthProvider` implements `IRequiresRequestContext` to use `RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().SaveSession(userSession, SessionExpiry);` but the `RequestContext` is `null`.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally solved the problem.

I added a ICacheClient property to my custom `AuthProvider` and resolved the dependency inside the `AppHost`.

```cs
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new MyCustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] 
        { new MyCustomAuthProvider(container.Resolve<ICacheClient>()) }
));
```

then inside the `AuthProvider.IsAuthorized()` I save the session using:

```cs
Cache.CacheSet(SessionKey, userSession, SessionExpiry);
```